# IBM IHS Reverse Proxy Configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, http, reverse-proxy, https, ihs

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy using IBM HTTP server and what I want to do is that user will hit a HTTP url to my reverse proxy server that will forward request internally to HTTPs server.

HTTP Address <--> Reverse Proxy (IBM HTTP Server) <--> HTTPS server (https://example.com)

In my configuration I have enabled mod_proxy & mod_proxy_http and configured below ProxyPass

```
Proxypass / https://example.com
```

But I am unable to configure it. I am getting error:

```
proxy: HTTPS: failed to enable SSL support for example.com
```

Anybody help what I might be doing wrong. I have also already loaded below modules:

```
LoadModule ibm_ssl_module modules/mod_ibm_ssl.so
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need `SSLProxyEngine ON` and a `KeyFile`